# Is a rules file all that is needed to access a usb device in RHEL8?

Tags: usb, debian, redhat-enterprise-linux

I have a USB camera connected to the computer, and it had been working properly when it ran Debian - I just put a rules file in `/etc/udev/rules.d/`. Recently the OS was changed to RHEL8, and this no longer works as my program keeps complaining being unable to find the camera. `lsusb` shows the device, rules file in place. I rebooted the computer expecting the rules would take effect (although I think it's not necessary), still not working. Are there any differences between Debian and RHEL8 for accessing such USB devices? Did I miss steps here?

Comment: One potential difference is that the kernel module Debian was using for your camera may or may not be present in RHEL8. Your rule file, which you didn't show us, probably said which kernel module to use. So have a look if this module is available on RHEL8.

Comment: The rules file has:

Comment: SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1e10", ATTRS{idProduct}=="4000", OWNER="usbuser", GROUP="usbuser", MODE="0660".

Comment: So I assume your created the user and the group `usbuser`, with the same id as before, and your program, when executed, belongs to this group? Also, the camera appears on boot? And gets the right owner and permissions? (Check `/dev/video*` and `dmesg`)?